# Wix Read and Write Network Service

Tags: windows-services, wix

I've been trying to get my .msi to install a service on my machine. I used exe4j to make my Java code, archived in .jar file, for it to be held in a .exe file. The service needs to have privileges to read and write across networks. I managed to get it all working except that the service hasn't got read and write privileges when account is set to 'NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService' in the ServiceInstall element.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        MainService instance = new MainService();
        instance.processArgs(args);
        watcher.run();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        error(e.getMessage());          
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(1);   // only get here after an exception
}
```

This is some of my WiX code

```
<File Name="tService.exe" Source="tService.exe" KeyPath="yes" />

<ServiceInstall Id="ServiceID" Description="Copies assets" ErrorControl="normal" Name="tService" Start="demand" Interactive="no" Type="ownProcess" Account="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" />

<ServiceControl Id="StartService" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="InterConnectService" Wait="yes" />
```

What Account do I need or how could I get Read and Write privileges with my service? I want the .msi file to install the service with these read and write privileges. I don't want to start creating accounts manually.

## Update:

'NetworkService' just fails at installation time with the msi "Service ... could not be installed. verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services". When I use 'NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService' the installation process works fine. However with 'NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService' I cannot read or write across networks.

Any ideas how I could read and write across networks? Your responses are much appreciated.

Comment: Is the install failing or does it succeed but the service is not set for NetworkService?

Answer (score 1):

As Rob asked, it will be helpful to know whether your installation fails or just doesn't set the permissions. However, you can anyway try this: in @Account attribute put just 'NetworkService', not the full 'domain\account' value. 'NetworkService' is one of the aliases provided by WiX toolset for well-known accounts - it will be mapped to the proper account correctly.

Answer (score -1):

The name of the service account is wrong, it needs to be `NT AUTHORITY\Network Service`.